# Android volley library, where to use and where not to

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley

As our typical old asynctask network connection is getting replaced by volley. It's fast as I have used so I know. I downloaded images and showed. When I again restarted the app it didn't take time to download. So is it caching images for sometime ? And as it is recommended not to use in heavy download, any reason ? Or it is the reason that it keeps images and all in memory ? I saw I/O video of volley. But I need clear explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mostly use Volley for only GET, POST api calls because Volley holds all responses in memory during parsing. For large download operations, consider using an alternative like [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html). Source: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I have used Volley in one project and it was simple for normal POST,GET but I think that I had quite some problems when I tried to upload an image.
So I would say that is quite good for making just POST,GET where you don't transfer a lot of data.